# Query con where dinámico en laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel, eloquent

¡Hola! Me gustaría saber ¿cuál es la manera correcta de armar un query con filtros dinámicos en eloquent (laravel 5.6) ?
Les comparto lo que es mi query básico, al cual se le pueden añadir nuevos filtro según lo requerido por el usuario:

```
  $listado = DB::connection('comments')
    ->table('dim.almacen AS al')
    ->join('fact.venta_comparada_extendida AS T1', 'T1.id_almacen', '=', 'al.id_almacen')
    ->select(DB::raw('al.des_almacen, sum(venta_ytd) as ventaactual, sum(venta_ppto) as ventapptoactual, sum(venta_yld'.$cc.') as ventaanterior, sum(venta_proy) as proyactual'))
    ->distinct('al.id_almacen')
    ->whereBetween('T1.id_calendario', [$date[0], $date[1]])
    ->groupBy('al.id_almacen', 'al.des_almacen');
```

Ahora bien, desde el controlador obtengo los parámetros de la vista que me indican que otros filtros debo agregar a la consulta, por ejemplo:

```
 if(isset($request['canal']) AND (!empty($request['canal']))) {
        $filtro .= " AND al.canalventa like '". $request['canal']."' ";
    }
 if(isset($request['cadenaventa']) AND (!empty($request['cadenaventa']))) {
        $filtro .= " AND al.cadenaventa like '". $request['cadenaventa']."' ";
    }

    if(isset($request['grupomall']) AND (!empty($request['grupomall']))) {
        $filtro .= " AND al.grupomall like '". $request['grupomall']."' ";
    }

    if(isset($request['mall']) AND (!empty($request['mall']))) {
        $filtro .= " AND al.des_almacen like '". $request['mall']."' ";
    }
```

Pero ésto quiero llevarlo al modelo, por lo que he intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    if(isset($request['canal']) AND (!empty($request['canal']))) 
        $listado = $listado->where(' al.canalventa like '.$request['canal'] );

    if(isset($request['grupomall']) AND (!empty($request['grupomall']))) 
        $listado = $listado->where(' al.grupomall ', ' like ', $request['grupomall'] );

    if(isset($request['mall']) AND (!empty($request['mall']))) 
        $listado = $listado->where(' al.des_almacen ', ' like ',  $request['mall'] );
```

"Reacomodando" el query original para que el

```
  ->groupBy('al.id_almacen', 'al.des_almacen');
```

Sea lo último en ejecutarse, pero no logro que funcione, me arroje éste error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 The multi-part identifier " al.canalventa like RETAIL" could not be bound. [20018] (severity 16) [select count(*) as aggregate from [dim].[almacen] as [al] inner join [fact].[venta_comparada_extendida] as [T1] on [T1].[id_almacen] = [al].[id_almacen] where [T1].[id_calendario] between 20180101 and 20181231 and [ al].[canalventa like RETAIL] is null group by [al].[id_almacen], [al].[des_almacen]] (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [dim].[almacen] as [al] inner join [fact].[venta_comparada_extendida] as [T1] on [T1].[id_almacen] = [al].[id_almacen] where [T1].[id_calendario] between 20180101 and 20181231 and [ al].[canalventa like RETAIL] is null group by [al].[id_almacen], [al].[des_almacen])
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

Te faltan los porcentajes en los where. Además los espacios en el where tanto donde ingresas la columna como en la condición (like).
Ejemplo:

```
if(isset($request['grupomall']) AND (!empty($request['grupomall']))) 
    $listado = $listado->where('al.grupomall', 'like', "%{$request['grupomall']}%" );
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, eso era lo que estaba haciendo mal.